# Does anyone know when Tar will Compress to .7z in the future? (It does xz compression, but when will it do 7zip -mx=9 compression?)

Tags: tar, 7zip

I use tar cvfpJ to do my maximum linux compression, but I want tar to do the 7zip compression in the future (instead of having to install p7zip). Do you guys know if this is in the plans for the future?

Thus... the only way is to do:

tar cvp | 7z a - ?

Since there is no **"tar cvfp7 Backup.tar.7z mySource/"**

Comment: Assuming you are referring to GNU tar (the implementation shipped in Ubuntu), only its developers can answer this question, but I suspect their answer would be "never."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like, as you said, the only way is:

```
tar cf - directory | 7z a -si directory.tar.7z
```

this is from man 7z:

> -si    Read data from StdIn (eg: tar cf - directory | 7z a -si directory.tar.7z)

For restoring, also from 7z man:

```
   On Linux/Unix, in order to backup directories you must use tar :
    - to backup a directory  : tar cf - directory | 7za a -si directory.tar.7z
    - to restore your backup : 7za x -so directory.tar.7z | tar xf -
```

Comment: and how do you unzip that 7z file ?

Comment: The one-liner to TAR+7zip LINUX is:         
tar cf - directory | 7z a -si directory.tar.7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9  /// EXTRACT: 7z x -so file.tar.7z | tar xf - -C target_dir

Answer (score 2):

`tar` does not do any compression.  It simply has options to automatically pipe its output to a program that does compression for you, saving you a bit of typing.  You still have to have have p7zip installed.

The difference between xz and 7z is that 7z contains extra data so that it can encode multiple files with msdos names.  The underlying compression algorithm is the same.  The multiple file support is not needed for a tar file since tar already bundles multiple files into one and with proper unix filename and permission support, and so that is why there is no option for 7z.  Just stick with xz.

Comment: For some reason when i do tar xvfpJ, its 14mb for my file, but 7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9, its only 400k. How do I do max compression for tar? can you tell me?